# Parameter passing through routing problem in Codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

I have a little routing problem, that i can't solve in Codeigniter 4.
I try adding a parameter at deleting list item. But get the following error messages.

> Error message at post routing: Controller or its method is not found:
> \App\Controllers\Userfeed::delete

> Error message at add or get routing: Controller or its method is not found:
> \App\Controllers\Pages::index

controllers file directory:
[image: controller_directory]

the relevant part of the Route file (it's in the Config directory):

```
$routes->get('/', 'Pages/Home::index');
$routes->get('userfeed', 'Pages/UserFeed::index');
$routes->post('userfeed/add', 'Pages/UserFeed::add');

//$routes->add('userfeed/(:any)', 'Pages/UserFeed::delete');//this works fine
$routes->get('userfeed/(:any)', 'Pages/UserFeed::delete');//this works fine
//$routes->get('userfeed/(:any)', 'Pages/UserFeed::delete/$1');//this is not work, which is the goal
//$routes->post('userfeed/(:any)', 'Pages/UserFeed::delete/$1');//this is not work
//$routes->add('userfeed/(:any)', 'Pages/UserFeed::delete/$1');//this is not work
...
```

the relevant part of the controller:

```
namespace App\Controllers\Pages;
use App\Controllers\MainCtrl;
...
class UserFeed extends MainCtrl{ 
....
public function delete($id=FALSE)
    {
        var_dump('wooot?');
        var_dump($id);
    }
}
```

the view part:

```
....
<a class="badge badge-secondary" href="<?php echo base_url('userfeed/delete/'.$rss['id']);?>" >Töröl</a>
....
```

But if i make a copy from this controller in the root controller directory, it's working.

```
$routes->get('userfeed/delete/(:any)', 'UserFeed2::delete/$1');//it's working fine
```

If need more information let it with me know.
Thanks your help! :)

**Note: *Thank God*, found the problem. :)**
**And one guess, one reward. =)**

Comment: Does the namespacing of your Controller files match their actual location on the filesystem?

Comment: Yes, it's matches.

Comment: As a good practice and also as a security feature, your method should be a DELETE not a GET. You should use a GET method only for retrieving data from server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

`$routes->get('userfeed/delete/(:any)', 'Pages\UserFeed::delete/$1');`

The difference is the slash used. You must use a backslash () not forward (/)

Comment: Thanks your help, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: But if i make a copy from this controller, and i put in the root controller directory, it's working. So almost. :)

Comment: Can you show me the structure of your controllers and the routes file?

Comment: route file relevant part:
$routes->get('/', 'Pages/Home::index');
$routes->get('userfeed', 'Pages/UserFeed::index');
$routes->post('userfeed/add', 'Pages/UserFeed::add');
$routes->add('userfeed/delete/(:any)', 'Pages/UserFeed::delete/$1');

conroller file relevant part:
namespace App\Controllers\Pages;
use App\Controllers\MainCtrl;
class UserFeed extends MainCtrl{
...
public function delete( $id = FALSE )
    { echo $id; }
...
}
Almost like in the original post.

Comment: I'm sorry if it was not clear, I meant that I want you to take a screenshot of the routes file and the files inside the Controllers folder.

Comment: I modified the post with a controllers directory picture. The Route file in the Config directory. The necessary route info in the post description.

Comment: Ok, your answer is correct. This is the mistake, that i have made. The reward is yours. =)